# Is there a "clean URL" (mod_rewrite) equivalent for iPlanet?

Tags: coldfusion, url-rewriting, cfc

I'm working with Coldfusion (because I have to) and we use iPlanet 7 (because we have to), and I would like to pass clean URL's instead of the query-param junk (for numerous reasons). My problem is I don't have access to the overall **obj.conf** file, and was wondering if there were **.htaccess** equivalents I could pass on the fly per directory. Currently I am using *Application.cfc* to force the server to look at *index.cfm* in root before loading the requested page, but this requires a **.cfm** file is passed, so it just 404's out if the user provides */path/to/file* but no extension. Ultimately, I would like to allow the user to pass **domain.com/path/to/file** but serve **domain.com/index.cfm?q1=path&q2=to&q3=file**. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exists for iPlanet, haven't had to work with it before.  But it would be possible to use a url like index.cfm/path/to/file, and pull the extra path information via the cgi.path_info variable.  Not exactly what you're looking for, but cleaner that query-params.

Comment: This is what I have been thinking of doing, and it makes sense, so I am going to go ahead and use it, thank you.

Comment: There are a few CF frameworks out there for building RESTful APIs that you may want to take a look at as well.  PowerNap and Taffy are the two that come to mind (http://powernap.riaforge.com and http://taffy.riaforge.com)

Comment: The .cfm hack works great, can't use frameworks since the computer is a classified machine and it takes months to get any new software on the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can mod_dir with the DirectoryIndex directive to set which page is served on /directory/ requests.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: I'm not sure how to use mod_dir on iplanet since I have no httpd config and the obj.conf is at the server layer, which I have no access to. I was looking for something a little more flexible akin to .htaccess so I could simply turn URL rewrite on or off.